# CSS adjust button size

Tags: html, css

```
.-m-refresh-btn {
background-image: url(../../content/icon/refresh.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-color: #fff;
width: 40px <--------------
```

}

```
.-m-second-button {
border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
border-radius: 4px;
height: 40px;
color: #000000;
padding: 0 24px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
```

i can't change width button with element width . what's element change width button . Thanks all

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve the grammar, add the HTML code for the button, and show or describe the undesired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a display property. Depends what elements you're trying to apply the styles to.

Comment: tks u so much <3